# How to select a proper model for my problem?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, scikit-learn

I need to calculate coefficients of a regression model using sklearn:

X =

```
x1          x2          x3   x4         x5    x6
0.300000    0.100000    0.0  0.0000     0.5   0.0
0.000000    0.006000    0.0  0.0000     0.2   0.0
0.010000    0.678000    0.0  0.0000     2.0   0.0
0.000000    0.333000    1.0  12.3966    0.1   4.0
0.200000    0.005000    1.0  0.4050     1.0   0.0
0.000000    0.340000    1.0  15.7025    0.5   0.0
0.000000    0.440000    1.0  8.2645     0.0   4.0
0.500000    0.055000    1.0  18.1818    0.0   4.0
```

The values of y are categorical in range [1; 4].

y =

```
1
2
1
3
4
1
2
3
```

If I apply logistic regression, I will get the 6x4 output. It means 6 coefficients for each categorical value of `y`. My goal is to get the equation like:

`y = a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 + d*x4 + e*x5 + f*x6`

However, if I apply a classical multiple linear regression, then I get `y` values like `3.4`, `3.3`, etc. I would round them, but all of them are always rounded to 4, for some reason.

Comment: By stating your y values are "categorical" you are asserting that the numbers you use to identify them have no meanings as numbers: they're just identifiers.  You could equally well use "a", "b", "c", "d".  What sense could the equation in your goal possibly make, then?

Comment: @whuber: Hmm, you are right. I didn't thought about it. Well, `1` means very good, `2` means good, etc. The equation should be able to approximate Y values. How can I get such equation? It looks like linear regression is not the best choice. Should I use the multinomial logistic regression, but in this case I get the 6x4 output. P.S. The question is mine, but I was unregistered.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ordered+logistic+regression.  And please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.